# VS Express 2012 Code View Scrollbar shrunk

Tags: visual-studio-2012, scrollbar, text-editor

Normally the vertical scrollbar in the text editor (code view) of Visual Studio Express 2012 runs the full length of the window you're viewing the text in.

After installing on a new machine, my new scrollbar is two sad little arrows, one up, one down, and cannot be navigated by moving the indicator inbetween them as there isn't one. If I split the view, I get two sets of scrolling nubs.

I've tried disabling and re-enabling the vertical scrollbar in Tools > Options > Text Editor > General. When disabled the miniature scrollbar goes away and comes back miniature if I re-enable.

Trying to figure out what setting or group of settings regulate this and how to get back my proper scrollbar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following worked for me

1. Go to %System Drive%\Users(user-account)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache
2. Rename the cache file (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.Cache) present there to 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.Cache_1'.
3. Restart the visual studio.

Comment: I gave up on this ages ago, and totally forgot I'd asked the question. This totally worked! Thank you so much!